# pandas ffill based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-01'],
    'category': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'rate': [0.5, 0.75, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1.25, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

I want to use `ffill` to forward fill the values of `rate`, except that I want each value to correspond also to the appropriate `category`. How can I get `df` to look like this?:

```
df
    category    date    rate
    1     2011-01-01    0.50
    2     2011-01-01    0.75
    1     2011-02-01    0.50
    2     2011-02-01    0.75
    1     2011-03-01    1.00
    2     2011-03-01    1.25
    1     2011-04-01    1.00
    2     2011-04-01    1.25
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('category').ffill()
```

Output:

```
   category        date  rate
0         1  2011-01-01  0.50
1         2  2011-01-01  0.75
2         1  2011-02-01  0.50
3         2  2011-02-01  0.75
4         1  2011-03-01  1.00
5         2  2011-03-01  1.25
6         1  2011-04-01  1.00
7         2  2011-04-01  1.25
```

If you have other columns with NaN that you don't want fill, then you can use this to just ffill NaN in  rate column:

```
df['rate'] = df.groupby('category')['rate'].ffill()
```

Comment: How to achieve this w/o getting rid of category column?

Comment: @haneulkim Add .reset_index() at the end ot move the 'category' column out of the index.